# Automatically resizing a guizero window

Tags: python, guizero

I have written a guizero code that creates a new window with different amounts of information on it depending on what is selected. I was just wondering if there is a function to resize the window to fit all of the information. I am currently just making the window big enough to fit the largest amount of information but I would rather have it so it resizes it automatically.
And also is there a simple function so that if the window size is changed all of the widgets inside of it change size as well?

Comment: I *think* you would have to do this yourself -- i.e. keeping track of the widgets displayed and updating the `app.width` and `app.height`.

What layout are you using. The layout may provide a way.

Comment: Ok I can code that easily enough, I'm not currently using a layout. I was just wondering if there was a specific function for this. I couldn't find one in the guizero documentation so I guess there isn't one. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I think is not possible to automaticly resize the window but you can count the number of lines and resize the window.

numLines*defaultHeightByLine + height of the other elements

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).